# How to use host network while linking to a container?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

In my docker-compose:

```
laravel:
    image: trackware
    links:
        - postgis:postgis
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "3306:3306"
        - "443:443"
        - "220:22"
        - "8000:8000"
    net: "host"
    restart:  always
    volumes:
        - C:/H/repositories/pubnub:/share
    container_name: laravel

postgis:
    image: mdillon/postgis
    env_file: .postgis_env
    ports:
        - "9090:9000"
        - "54320:5432"
    container_name: postgis
```

if I run `docker-compose up -d` I get this error:

```
Conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior
```

So, how would I use `net: "host"` while linking to postgis container?
laravel container needs to run pubnub client, which will need high-performance networking for real time messages handling, and also it needs to link to `postgis` container to access db.

So, any advice? I am using docker 1.10.2

Comment: Was there anything PubNub related that needs consideration? Doesn't look like there is but thought I'd ask.

Comment: No, there is nothing related to PubNub here

Comment: You may want to remove the laravel tag from this question given that it appears to be a general docker-compose question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you expose postgis ports to host, you can skip linking and connect to it through `localhost:9000`. I believe this will work since the Laravel application resides on the host network and they will share those ports.

Comment: I was trying to connect django container to postgis container on 127.0.0.1, but it worked only for localhost.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why we use links keyword is so that docker can internally make hostname resolution so that two disparate containers can communicate with each other.
In your case if you were not using host network and using the link keyword then docker would have created a hostname with each container names internally so both containers can communicate with each others.
When you are using "host" mode network means you are telling docker that i shall be using the "hosts" underlying network and hence by simply exposing the ports on the localhost my containers can communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno reason but... You shouldn't use "host" driver and port mapping, at least you wouldn't get expected result. In case like this "220:22" you'll get 22 port mapped to the host machine.

"Net" is outdated as far as I know, use "[network_mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-mode)" instead. 
Also I would recommend you to update docker-compose to the latest version, now is 1.6.2. Previous versions had some networking problems.

May be you can use "[bridge](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#a-bridge-network)" driver? In your case, I can't see problems which it couldn't resolve.

Comment: How would I update docker-compose at windows ? How to covert docker-compose file to version 2?

Comment: Sorry, not sure about Windows. Try run [toolbox](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox) and check "docker-compose" box. 
About converting compose file, in your case, just add version and services sections. Here more about it [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)